# Class member variable

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm starting to learn c++ and as far as I could find, I can only find primitive types as class members.

Why is the following giving me an error: missing type identifier - int assumed?

```
class CarManager
{
public:
    void Drive();

private:
    Car car;
};
```

Tried all combinations I could think of:

```
Car car = new Car();
Car *car = new Car();
Car &car = new Car();
```

All have their own errors.

Comment: The first code block is correct, but it doesn't know `Car` exists.

Comment: where is `Car` defined?

Comment: Its on the project, if I declare it on main method it works fine, i dont get it

Comment: Did you declare the `Car` type before this? Order is important.

Comment: Only the second is semantically correct.

Comment: this is an existing API and I am trying to create a class to wrap it if it helps, but the example they have is on main method and im trying to create a class

Comment: If `Car` is in a header file, do you have the `#include` line before this?

Comment: @Barmar thank you, I missed the #include for it. Can't believe wasted so many hours on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `Car` must be defined: add `#include "Car.h"` before CarManager definition.

Then, if car attribute is an object (as proposed in your example), it must have a default constructor or be initialized upon CarManager constructor:

```
class CarManager
{
public:
    CarManager() : car(...construction parameters...) {} // to be moved in cpp file, of course!
    void Drive();

private:
    Car car;
};
```

Note: If it's a pointer (`Car* car;`) or a reference (`Car& car;`), you don't need to include Car.h, a forward declaration would do (`class Car;` instead of `#include "Car.h"`). Then, include Car.h from CarManager.cpp when initializing the pointer/reference.

Jean